# Awk conditional if else

Tags: awk

i have a file that doesn't want to messed up the sequence so i'm trying to work out my awk conditional statement.

if $3 has TB(string), remove it and multiply it by 1024 and if it has GB just remove it(remove the string GB) and do nothing.

```
sast1sis01_002          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00GB   60050912017086C7700000000000021E
sast1sis01_004          iresas-p2-ris03    50.00TB    60050912017086C77000000000000AAF
sast1sis01_003          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00GB   60050912017086C77000000000000BB0
sast1sis01_008          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00GB   60050912017086C77000000000000OO1
sast1sis01_005          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00GB   60050912017086C77000000000000212
sast1sis01_001          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00GB   60050912017086C77000000000000993
arrysas1_356            cbscc-u8-msas1     600.00GB   60050912017086C77000000000000BBA
N8DVP01ABC_007          iresas-z1-pit02    2.44TB     60050912017086C770000000000005EE
n2sql90abc_052          iresas-p2-sql57a   1.00TB     60050912017086C7700000000000089C
n3sq321abc_055          iresas-p2-sql57b   0          60050912017086C7700000000000011C
n6sq222abc_056          iresas-p2-sql57a   1.00GB     60050912017086C7700000000000022D
n7sqbascka_058          iresas-p2-sql57b   0          60050912017086C7700000000000039D
```

Trying this out:

```
awk '{s=($3=="TB")?"-":$3=$3*1024; print}';awk '{s=($3=="GB")?"-":'s/GB//g'; print}' file
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
awk '
$3~/[tT][bB]$/{
  temp=substr($3,1,length($3)-2)
  $3=temp*1024
}
$3~/[gG][bB]/{
  $3=substr($3,1,length($3)-2)
}
1
' Input_file |column -t
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                   ##Starting awk program from here.
$3~/[tT][bB]$/{                         ##Checking condition if 3rd field is equal to tT OR bB then do following.
  temp=substr($3,1,length($3)-2)        ##Creating variable temp  which has sub-string from 3rd field.
  $3=temp*1024                          ##Re-creating 3rd field which has value of temp variable and multiplying it with 1024 here.
}
$3~/[gG][bB]/{                          ##Checking condition if 3rd field is having gG OR bB then do following.
  $3=substr($3,1,length($3)-2)          ##Re-creating 3rd field which has value of 3rd field apart from last 2 char of it.
}
1                                       ##Printing current line here.
' Input_file | column -t                 ##Putting output of awk program to column command to beautify it.
```

Comment: quick question. If i wanted to include the floating value which one should i edit here?

Comment: @gafm, you couldue like `$3=sprintf("%.04f",temp*1024)` which will have floating point till 4 points, lemme know in case of any questions here.

Comment: great, @RavinderSingh13, will that also preserves say for example $1 has a data with spaces?

Comment: @gafm, spaces part already taken care, by using column it beautifies space in output.

Comment: Thanks for your help as always. Can you also take a look at this one please [Preserved Column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62075112/treat-first-column-with-spaces-as-one-column-using-awk?noredirect=1#comment109804200_62075112)

Answer (score 3):

```
awk '$3 ~ /TB$/ { $3 *= 1024 }; $3 ~ /GB$/ { $3 += 0 }; 1'
```

The above command works. `awk` converts strings to numbers automatically from starting part of the string. Here it ignores `GB` and `TB` part.

If you care about having 2 digits of precision after decimal even if they are just zeroes than you can use.

```
awk '$3 ~ /TB$/ { $3 *= 1024 }; $3 ~ /GB$/ { $3 += 0 };  {$3 = sprintf("%.2f", $3) } 1'
```

Comment: `awk '$3 ~ /TB$/ { $3 = $3*1024 }; $3 ~ /GB$/ { $3 = $3+0 };  {$3 = sprintf("%.2f", $3) } 1'`

This destroys the sequence of the file. leaving lines with TB's are only converted.

Comment: I understand that 'sequence', here,  means the order of the lines. Order of lines is preserved in this command. In the second command, there is only unnecessary modification of lines which may be left alone. The second part of answer is only useful if the loss of trailing zeros after decimal is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Since this is fixed-width data, with GNU awk you can write:

```sh
gawk '
  BEGIN {FIELDWIDTHS = "24 19 11 *"; OFS=""}
  {$3 = sprintf("%-11.2f", $3 * ($3 ~ /TB/ ? 1000  : 1))}
  1
' file
```

outputs:

```
sast1sis01_002          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00     60050912017086C7700000000000021E
sast1sis01_004          iresas-p2-ris03    50000.00   60050912017086C77000000000000AAF
sast1sis01_003          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00     60050912017086C77000000000000BB0
sast1sis01_008          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00     60050912017086C77000000000000OO1
sast1sis01_005          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00     60050912017086C77000000000000212
sast1sis01_001          iresas-p2-ris03    100.00     60050912017086C77000000000000993
arrysas1_356            cbscc-u8-msas1     600.00     60050912017086C77000000000000BBA
N8DVP01ABC_007          iresas-z1-pit02    2440.00    60050912017086C770000000000005EE
n2sql90abc_052          iresas-p2-sql57a   1000.00    60050912017086C7700000000000089C
n3sq321abc_055          iresas-p2-sql57b   0.00       60050912017086C7700000000000011C
n6sq222abc_056          iresas-p2-sql57a   1.00       60050912017086C7700000000000022D
n7sqbascka_058          iresas-p2-sql57b   0.00       60050912017086C7700000000000039D
```